# Manipulating a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>

    <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The first 2 items are fine but the items 3-14 I need to wrap in a div so I can control the layout. I am wondering how I would do this? The problem is not all of the 3-14 items will be populated.

Any advice would be welcome ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

So with your additions, since the original formula should work, don't mess with that part. Instead make an addition via a `$style` variable like so:

```
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField):
        if($i == 1)
            $style  =    'id="largeImageWrap" class="pull-left"';
        elseif($i == 2)
            $style  =   'id="sidePanelWrap"';
        else
            $style  =   'class="row"';

          // If less than or equal to 3, add <div>
         if(($i <= 3))
            $front  =   true;
        // If greater than 14 <div>
        elseif(($i > 14))
            $front  =   true;
        // Else no <div>
        else
            $front  =   false;

        if($front == true) echo "<div $style>"; ?>

         <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>

    <?php
        // If greater than 2 and less than 14 echo blank or </div>
        echo (($i > 2) && ($i < 14))? "":"
        </div>";
    $i++;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: OK. So what If wanted to expand on that and do something like this:

    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3-14</div>

Comment: Like you want want to have all 3 - 14 inside the div?

Comment: Yes. Plus item 1 and 2 in their own divs. So I am presuming an elseif ?

Comment: I made a couple less than greater than errors, see revision(s).

Comment: Take a look at what I have so far. The only problem is ... it is adding <div class="row"> to EVERY item and not wrapping it around all of those items?

Comment: Ok take a look at what I have revised. It should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a control variable to determine which iteration you are at, from there you can add divs or whatever you want to do from the third iteration onward. You could try something like this:

```
 <?php $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField): ?>

   <?php $i++;
    if ($i < 3) { ?>

    <span class="itemExtraFieldsValue"><?php echo $extraField->value; ?></span>

 <?php   } else { ?>

     Add divs, or whatever you want to do here.

   <?php }

     endforeach; ?>
```